# Reshaping 1D array does not work properly

Tags: python-3.x

Assume I have the following array, where all binary values are assumed to be in the same length:

```
A = [10101010, 10011010, 10111101, 11110000]
```

This is 1D of size `4`. I want to be able to convert it to 2D `numpy`. Thus, using this example I should get `(4,8)`. I use the following code but it doesn't reshape it. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np

A = [10101010, 10011010, 10111101, 11110000]
A = np.asarray(A)
A = np.reshape(A, [-1,])
```

Comment: invalid representation of binary values - you got huges ints, bigger then 1 million

Comment: @PatrickArtner It is an array of binary values to be converted to 2D. what's wrong with that?

Comment: `A` is a list containing 10miliion101thousand10, 10million11thousand10, 10million111thousand101,11million110thousand. Not binary values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a list of integers that are > 10 million each - not binary values.

You can fix that by making them a string, seperate into single digits and convert that:

```
import numpy as np

A = [10101010, 10011010, 10111101, 11110000]
B = [list(map(int,t)) for t in list(map(str,A))]
npA = np.asarray(B) 
print(npA)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]]
```